# Barcode Human Readable Text ( Interpretation Line) masking in ZPL II

Tags: textfield, zpl-ii

I am trying to make a ZPL Label with Code 128. My issue is that I would like to alter the human readbale interpretation line under the barcode. Normally, it gets printed as what it is encoded, i want to add spaces after 5 characters (as picture).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcBqS.png)
I was able to do it in Zebra designer but we have to store the label as ZPL and if I export the .prn file it gets encrypted  and i get always the same barcode printed, which in my case is not correct.

I tried to turn off BC interpretation line and used ^FN to print interpretation line and do some formatting on it but after going through internet and ZPLII manuals , I am unable to find anything.

content of .prn file, i am getting:
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA
~TA000
~JSN
^LT0
^MNW
^MTT
^PON
^PMN
^LH0,0
^JMA
^PR4,4
~SD15
^JUS
^LRN
^CI27
^PA0,1,1,0
^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW2457
^LL1200
^LS0
^FO652,258^GFA,2573,46768,148,:Z64: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:AC0D
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ

Comment: Please show the resulting ZPL code or your exported prn file.

Comment: @DelphiCoder it is quite big to copy paste here, I will try to attach it to this question.